# SagePay Multilingual - text not in templates

Tags: multilingual, opayo

We're trying to implement a Welsh set of templates for SagePay for a customer.

We've gone through the process, have uploaded the templates and all is working ok so far, except there's still some EN text showing and we can't see anywhere in the templates where we can localise this.

Specifically on the carddetails page:

[image]

and:

[image]

Any suggestions on where/how we can set translated strings for this text?

Comment: Do you honestly think anyone can answer this for you with the information provided? We don't even know which framework you are using, what language it's written in, how is the template set up? etc...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that message is sent direct from the payment gateway, so can't be internationalised.